# Issues with SQL statement INERT INTO SELECT FROM WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Whats wrong with this?

```
mysqli_query($con, "
        INSERT INTO members (`ip`) VALUES ('$localIP') 
        SELECT * FROM members 
        WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$pword'");
```

Nothing gets inserted, and i dont get an error either.

Comment: Are you attempting to do two separate queries? I find it hard to believe that you are not getting MySQL syntax errors.  Most likely you are not actually trying to handle errors. Can you show more code context?

Comment: I am trying to insert where, but i read that i had to use SELECT with the insert statement

Comment: I do a mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection attacks.  Are you attempting `INSERT INTO SomeTable(Col1, ...) SELECT Col1, ... FROM SomeOtherTable`?  If so, the VALUES clause is unneeded.  As it stands, you have 2 SQL statements not separated by a semicolon.  That's going to lead to chaos.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have enough points to leave a comment on this but if you insert this into script you should be able to provide more information.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: I should use UPDATE and not INSERT, fixed, my bad